# Testing implementation of Symfony 2 Finder component with PhpSpec

Tags: php, symfony, tdd, php-5.6, phpspec

I get the following error when testing accessing the file system in my Symfony 2 application with the `Filesystem` component and then accessing the list of files in a directory with the `Finder` component.

`Call to undefined method Prophecy\Prophecy\MethodProphecy::in()`

This is a snippet of my method which I am testing:

```
$finder = new Finder();

if ($filesystem->exists($imageImportPath)) {
   $finder->files()->in($imageImportPath);
   foreach ($finder as $image) {         
      // ...do some stuff in here with uploading images and creating an entity...
      $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
      $this->entityManager->flush($entity);
   }    
}
```

This is my spec for the helper class:

```
function it_imports_image_assets(
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    EntityManager $entityManager,
    Finder $finder
) {
    $imageImportPath = '/var/www/crmpicco/app/files/images/rfc-1872/';
    $filesystem->exists($imageImportPath)->willReturn(true);

    $finder->files()->in($imageImportPath)->shouldHaveCount(2);

    $this->importImageAssets($imageImportPath)->shouldReturn([]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to test your method using real files (looking at the code I assume you want to do it), tests should work without it. You need to unit test your code, thus you can fake the files paths found by `Finder` to whatever you like, the code should not rely on some 3rd party files in order to pass the tests.

You will want to return `Finder` object on `$finder->files()` method, see below:

```
$finder->files()->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($finder);
$finder->in($imageImportPath)->willReturn($finder);

$finder->getIterator()->willReturn(new \ArrayIterator([
    $file1->getWrappedObject(),
    $file2->getWrappedObject(),
]));
```

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;
//..

function it_imports_image_assets(
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    EntityManager $entityManager,
    Finder $finder,
    SplFileInfo $file1,
    SplFileInfo $file2
) {
    $imageImportPath = '/var/www/crmpicco/app/files/images/rfc-1872/';
    $filesystem->exists($imageImportPath)->willReturn(true);
    $finder->files()->willReturn($finder);
    $finder->in($imageImportPath)->willReturn($finder);

    $finder->getIterator()->willReturn(new \ArrayIterator([
        $file1->getWrappedObject(),
        $file2->getWrappedObject(),
    ]));

    $file1->getPathname()->willReturn($imageImportPath.'file1.txt');
    $file2->getPathname()->willReturn($imageImportPath.'file1.txt');

    //...

    $this->importImageAssets($imageImportPath)->shouldReturn([]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't work for me though. I am getting the following error: `some predictions failed:
          Double\Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder\P17:
            No calls have been made that match:
              Double\Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder\P17->files()
            but expected at least one.`

Comment: try to remove `shouldBeCalled()` from `$finder->files()->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($finder);`

Comment: Thank you! Can you update your answer and I will gladly accept?

Comment: Updated. I'm glad it helped!